# Forcing ACMsmall to expand subfloat to whole page

Tags: subfloats, acm

I am having 6 different figures as `subfloatA11` to `subfloatA32`, using `subfloat`, I would like to force latex to automatically assign whole page to those figures making the most out of the space they can occupy, instead of me making this mess as below:

```
\newcommand{\sfigbigbig}[0]{9.8cm}
\newcommand{\sfigbigwhole}[0]{14.5cm}
\newcommand{\sfigbig}[0]{7.0cm}
\newcommand{\sfigmedium}[0]{5cm}
\newcommand{\sfigmediumP}[0]{5cm}
\newcommand{\sfigsmall}[0]{2.0cm}
\newcommand{\sfigfullcol}[0]{\sfigbigbig}
%---

\usepackage{subfig}
\documentclass[prodmode,acmtaco]{acmsmall} % Aptara syntax
\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[t!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rr}
\hspace{-50pt}  
\subfloat[subfloatA11]{\includegraphics[width = \sfigbigbig,height=0.35\textwidth]{figures/subfloatA01.eps}} &
\hspace{-30pt}  
\subfloat[subfloatA12]{\includegraphics[width = \sfigbigbig,height=0.35\textwidth]{figures/subfloatA12].eps}} \\\
\hspace{-50pt}  
\subfloat[subfloatA21]]{\includegraphics[width = \sfigbigbig,height=\sfigmedium]{figures/subfloatA22].eps}} &
\hspace{-30pt}  
\subfloat[subfloatA22]{\includegraphics[width = \sfigbigbig,height=\sfigmediumP]{figures/subfloatA32.eps}} \\
\hspace{-50pt}  
\subfloat[subfloatA31]{\includegraphics[width = \sfigbigbig,height=\sfigmedium]{figures/subfloatA31.eps}} &
\hspace{-30pt}  
\subfloat[subfloatA32]{\includegraphics[width = \sfigbigbig,height=\sfigmediumP]{figures/subfloatA32.eps}} 
\end{tabular}
\caption{Performance}
\label{fig:perf}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to specify both `width` and `height`? This will distort the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of assigning absolute widths, such as `9.8cm`, to the graphs, consider assigning relative widths, such as `0.475\textwidth`.

I'd get rid of the `\hspace{-30pt}` and `\hspace{-50pt}` statements.

```
\documentclass[prodmode,acmtaco]{acmsmall} % Aptara syntax

\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t!]

\subfloat[subfloatA11]{\includegraphics[width = 0.475\textwidth,
   height=0.35\textwidth]{figures/subfloatA01.eps}}
\hspace*{\fill} % horizontal space between two subfigures
\subfloat[subfloatA12]{\includegraphics[width = 0.475\textwidth,
   height=0.35\textwidth]{figures/subfloatA12].eps}}

\subfloat[subfloatA21]{\includegraphics[width = 0.475\textwidth,
   height=0.35\textwidth]{figures/subfloatA22].eps}}
\hspace*{\fill} % horizontal space between two subfigures
\subfloat[subfloatA22]{\includegraphics[width = 0.475\textwidth,
   height=0.35\textwidth]{figures/subfloatA32.eps}} 

\subfloat[subfloatA31]{\includegraphics[width = 0.475\textwidth,
   height=0.35\textwidth]{figures/subfloatA31.eps}} 
\hspace*{\fill} % horizontal space between two subfigures
\subfloat[subfloatA32]{\includegraphics[width = 0.475\textwidth,
   height=0.35\textwidth]{figures/subfloatA32.eps}} 

\caption{Performance}
\label{fig:perf}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: nice and neat answer. Awesome!

Answer (score 2):

From the description and the code, I guess you want the images to occupy part of the outer margins.

Here's a possibility, I left a very small separation at the center.

```
\documentclass[prodmode,acmtaco]{acmsmall} % Aptara syntax
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{figure}[!tp]
\centering

\setkeys{Gin}{height=3cm} % just for the example

\makebox[\textwidth]{%
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}
  \subfloat[subfloatA11]{\includegraphics[width = .6\textwidth]{example-image}} &
  \subfloat[subfloatA11]{\includegraphics[width = .6\textwidth]{example-image}} \\
  \subfloat[subfloatA11]{\includegraphics[width = .6\textwidth]{example-image}} &
  \subfloat[subfloatA11]{\includegraphics[width = .6\textwidth]{example-image}} \\
  \subfloat[subfloatA11]{\includegraphics[width = .6\textwidth]{example-image}} &
  \subfloat[subfloatA11]{\includegraphics[width = .6\textwidth]{example-image}}
  \end{tabular}%
}
\caption{Performance}
\label{fig:perf}

\end{figure}

\lipsum[4-10]

\end{document}
```

The lines with `% just for the example` are not meant for the production version.

Setting both height and width for the images will distort them, so I don't think it's really what you want.

[image]

With the same idea, you can try filling up a page:

```
\documentclass[prodmode,acmtaco]{acmsmall} % Aptara syntax
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{figure}[p]
\centering

\setkeys{Gin}{height=.28\textheight} % fill up the page

\makebox[\textwidth]{%
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}
  \subfloat[subfloatA11]{\includegraphics{example-image}} &
  \subfloat[subfloatA11]{\includegraphics{example-image}} \\
  \subfloat[subfloatA11]{\includegraphics{example-image}} &
  \subfloat[subfloatA11]{\includegraphics{example-image}} \\
  \subfloat[subfloatA11]{\includegraphics{example-image}} &
  \subfloat[subfloatA11]{\includegraphics{example-image}}
  \end{tabular}%
}
\caption{Performance}
\label{fig:perf}

\end{figure}

\lipsum[4-10]

\end{document}
```

Of course this might fail if the images turn out to be too wide for the given height.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @egreg, but this method isn't force the figures to be whole page. any ideas?

Comment: @Amir What do you mean? I can't understand: either you want to fix the width or the height, not both. If the heights sum up to be almost the page height, the float will occupy a page by itself.

Comment: Yes. But i wanted to have a full dynamic control of the page. Now in this case by fixing `\setkeys{Gin}{height=5.8cm}` I am ok, but for another latex template you need to change it again, cuz down bottom at footer, you have the journal name title.

Comment: @Amir I discourage you from doing this; however, something like `height=.28\textheight` should leave enough space for the subcaption and the main caption. I added some sample code.

Comment: thanks!! another thing: if my figures are not having the same size, could u hint me of a workaround to supersede its own size and make all 6 subfigs the same size?

Comment: @Amir If they don't have the same size, you'd distort them.